# How to change date format in Excel

Tags: excel

I am unable to convert the date formats in column2 and column3 as shown below.

Any tips how can I change it?

I have a column 01.01.2018. This needs to be changed to 1/1/2018 and other column 01/Jan/2018

```
01.01.2018  1/1/2018    01/Jan/2018
01.01.2018  1/1/2018    01/Jan/2018
01.12.2017  12/1/2017   01/Dec/2017
```

Comment: First check whether what you have in a cell is actually date or just a string of text characters which looks like a date. If the cell is text, you will need to use string functions to pull out the day, month and year bits, convert these to numbers and then re-assemble into an Excel date. There are Excel functions to do all these things. Dates can be displayed in different ways using Excel's cell formatting.

Comment: in an empty cell, use the formula `=istext(A1)`, where A1 is a cell containing a date from your first column and let us know the results.

Comment: =ISTEXT(AS2) value has is TRUE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Col A has date in a format Excel doesn't recognize by default. First convert that into a proper date in Excel. You can do that by following formula:

```
=DATE(RIGHT(A1,4),RIGHT(LEFT(A1,5),2),LEFT(A1,2))
```

Where A1 refers to 01.01.2018 in your example. Now you have converted it to a date, you can change the format to following custom formats:

For format 1/1/2018:

```
m/d/yyyy
```

For Format 01/Jan/2018

```
[$-409]dd-mmm-yyyy;@
```

PS: You can refer to following link for setting custom formats in Excel:

https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/07/07/custom-excel-number-format/